# Matrix Multiplication Modulo 2

Tags: function-construction, matrix, modular-arithmetic

I would like to perform matrix multiplication modulo 2. Hence, instead of the usual:
`A.B`

I did:

> `Inner[#1*#2 &, A, B, Modulus[#1+#2,2]&]`

However, it does not work, since `#1+#2` (in the modulus) only adds the first two inputs, whereas, I want it to add all its inputs (like `Plus` does). I want to define a function that just adds up all its inputs, modulo 2 **and it can take in variable number of inputs**.

In otherwords, I want to define a `addmod` which takes in variable number of inputs and adds them (modulo 2):

> `addmod[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] = 1`, `addmod[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] = 1`

and so on. Note, the input is not a list here. Hence I cannot say something like:

`addmod[list]=Fold[Modulus[Plus[#1+#2,2],2]&,0,list]`

I would be happy to get some help on this. Sorry, if i am missing out something basic.

Thanks very much.

Comment: There is no `Modulus[]` function in *Mathematica*...

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I intended to mean `Mod[... , 2]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
addmod = Mod[Plus[##],2]&
```

`##` is a `Sequence` of all the arguments given to `addmod`.